# Which Flutter plugins can help me with table annotation?

Tags: flutter, dart, annotations

I am writing a cross-platform app that should draw a table over a pdf and annotate the information in the pdf. I'm stuck at the part where I should make a dynamic table with moving rows and columns which can be deleted independently or added if I want more rows or columns. All this should be done by a user in the app itself. Which plugins or packages should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Flutter there is no plugin that can help you with table, but you can use table package
[enter link description here](https://pub.dev/packages/table)

Comment: Will the editable package be of any help? https://pub.dev/packages/editable

Comment: Yes it can help you, but not at all. If you wanna work like a pro you should prefer table package.

Comment: can I make my own table with custompaint?

Comment: No you can't, If you dont wont those options you can also use Row and Column widgets for table.